# Android Gradle build, Android Plugin version

Tags: android, gradle

I know that the Android Plugin version and the Gradle version
have to "match", or it wants you to use a specific version of Gradle.

So my question is, how can I find what version, '0.9.2', of the Android Plugin
it wants in:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'
```

I've found that if the version is "close enough" it will download/update what
it needs to make it happy, otherwise it'll give you an error.

So is there any command I can issue, or file to look at, that will
tell me what version to put in place of '0.9.2' so that I can
do a 'gradle build' with the version of Gradle that I have installed?

And I want to be able to just run 'gradle' and not 'gradlew.bat'

Thanks!

Comment: Android Gradle plugin docs and error message should say. I'm not aware of a command that tells which plugin versions a particular Gradle version is compatible with. In any case, I highly recommend to use `gradlew` instead of `gradle`.

Comment: There is no command but you can lookup the version of gradle required by each plugin in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system . For example, it tells you that version 0.9.0 is compatible with Gradle 1.10 and 1.11.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that link before.  I guess that's the closest I'm going to get.  I thought I saw some obscure script somewhere that would help print it out.  I have to look more into gradlew, but since it isn't part of a Gradle install, I want to try to stick to only using 'gradle' commands.